# Batch to check and display the last time of change of a specific file

Tags: batch-file

I would like a batch that check and display if and when a file was changed.

If C:\temp\test\TEST.LOG has changed today (*the day of the check*), display/echo time of change.  (ex: "**File changed 16:55**")

If Not C:\temp\test\TEST.LOG has changed today (*the day of the check*), display/echo "**File has not been changed today**"

Comment: Can you post the earliest version of Windows this has to run on? I've posted a PowerShell suggestion but this will only work on Windows 2000 and later from memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do this would be to launch PowerShell, which has massively more powerful functions for datetime manipulation, and file interrogation. You can run this from a batch file like so:

```
powershell -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "& { if ($(Get-Item c:\temp\test\test.log).LastWriteTime-gt [DateTime]::Today) { Write-Host "File Changed at $(Get-Item c:\temp\test\test.log).LastWriteTime" } else { Write-Host "File not changed" }}"
```

Here is the powershell command formatted more nicely, for your understanding

```
if ($(Get-Item c:\temp\test\test.log).LastWriteTime-gt [DateTime]::Today) {
    Write-Host "File Changed at $(Get-Item c:\temp\test\test.log).LastWriteTime"
}
else {
    Write-Host "File not changed" 
}
```

Comment: Your code works **BUT** seems only to display "File Changed at..." if the log-fil has been **created**, not **changed/updated**.

The test.log is not created every day, it's updated with more data.

Comment: Sorry - that should be `LastWriteTime` not `CreationTime`. I misread the question.

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "targetfile=c:\temp\test\test.log"
IF NOT EXIST %targetfile% ECHO %targetfile% does NOT exist&GOTO :eof
FOR %%a IN ("%targetfile%") DO FOR /f "tokens=1*delims= " %%b IN ('ECHO %%~ta') DO IF "%date%"=="%%b" (
 ECHO File changed %%c
) ELSE ECHO File has NOT been changed today
GOTO :EOF
```

This should work. You may need to tickle the `tokens=` and `delims` depending on your date/time settings.

Simply, find the target's date/time, split it into the date portion in `%%b` and time in `%%c`. Compare `%%b` to the current date; if the same, it's been changed today so show the file's date from `%%c` otherwise, it hasn't been changed today.